# Настройка Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Люди добрые, скоро сутки будут как я страдаю.
Вот в этом графике http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/intraday-breaks/sand-signika не как не могу добиться что б в стате округлить до целого числа значения. У меня там будут числа только от `0` до `~1000` передавая целое число к примеру `20` получаю там `20.00`. И если `0`, то в графике появляется полоска справа `-10`.
В англ. не силен, с переводчиком тут http://api.highcharts.com/highstock инфы не нашел :(

Comment: Я правильно понял, что Вам нужно, чтобы в тултипе значение округлялось до целых, как-то вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/9g9dv8sv/ ?
Тогда это `series.tooltip.valueDecimals = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нули после запятой добавляет опция `tooltip.valueDecimals`, уберите ее совсем или поставьте 0 если передаете графику дробные данные.

И устанавливаем минимум по ординате сами:

```
yAxis: {
  min: 0
}
```